# Querying EF and saving results (records) into a list?

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have a `List` of `QuestionData`. The `QuestionData` class is explained below:

```
class QuestionData
{
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public List<Option> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

I am using EF as ORM (Note: `Question` and `Option` used in `QuestionData` both are EF's auto generated entities).

Both tables (`Question`s and `Option`s) have PK-FK relationship. I want to fill list of `QuestionData` as I have to display `Question`s and answers under them. How do I fill `QuestionData`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using(QuestionContext context = new QuestionContext())
{
    List<QuestionData> questionDatas = 
       context.Questions.Select(q => new QuestionData()
       {
          Question = q.Value,
          Answers = q.Options.ToList()
       });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yeonho, it is giving 2 errors. Can you please guide.

1. On .Select(q  it give error: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

2. On q.Options  it give error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<CreativeFactory.Questionnaire.DAL.Option>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<CreativeFactory.Questionnaire.DAL.Option>' 

Kindly guide.

Comment: On error 1, I assumed that Question Entity has a string property named Value. you should modify this code according to your schema.
On error 2, try adding .ToList() to q.Options. hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Yeonho's answer, I think you probably need something like this:

```
using(QuestionContext context = new QuestionContext())
{
    List<QuestionData> questionDatas = 
       context.Questions.Select(q => new QuestionData()
       {
          Question = q,
          Answers = q.Options.ToList()
       });
}
```